# Lightroom Alternative That Doesn't Use a Catalog

Tags: raw, software, photo-editing, software-recommendation, open-source

I am looking for lightweight Lightroom alternatives that have the following features.
It's fine (even preferable) if this set of features is satisfied by multiple programs working together rather than a single monolithic program.

1. **No catalog!** This is my most important criteria. I want this software to work on *network-mounted* plain directories containing images (jpeg or raw), with no catalog or extra import steps.
2. **RAW support.** I need support for Fuji X-T10 and Fuji X-E2 RAF files, but obviously the more supported formats  the better.
3. **A *fast* way of culling files.**
4. **Basic *batch* darkroom-style adjustements.** I only do very basic image manipulation, mostly the same things I'd do in a traditional darkroom:

   - cropping
   - color balance
   - curves adjustement
   - dodge and burn

   I'd also like support for:

   - noise reduction
   - lens correction

   I'd like to be able to do these opearations in batch over a set of files.
5. **Native macOS look and feel.** For example rawTherapee doesn't feel like a native macOS program. I'm okay with command-line programs where it makes sense.

I don't *need* this, but **XMP support** (in sidecar files) would be great.

I'm open to any kind of program, commercial or open source, as long as it has the features I want, and as long as ***it's not* subscription-based.**

Comment: Have you looked at Fuji's [*Raw File Converter*](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/software/myfinepix_studio/rfc/)? It doesn't exactly have a sexy name, but it is designed by Fuji to convert raw files from their cameras.

Comment: I tried it and found it awful, it's a PITA to use and it doesn't have HiDPI support. In my opinion [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) is a far better option if all you want is pure raw conversion. Raw conversion is the easy part though, it's the image editing part which is difficult. I've been told that [Capture One](https://www.phaseone.com/en/Products/Software/Capture-One-Pro/Highlights.aspx) has a session-based workflow instead of a catalog-based workflow, so maybe I should try that.

Comment: For a Fuji-specific dcraw frontend, I have found [Iridient X-Transformer](http://www.iridientdigital.com/products/xtransformer.html) to be excellent. There's also the generic [Iridient Developer](http://www.iridientdigital.com/products/iridientdeveloper.html). These are all great tools, but they don't do #3 and #4 from my list.

Comment: I passed over Lightroom for a similar catalog reason. Too much unwanted stuff between me and my images. I just use Photoshop, it is the same ACR module that is in Lightroom, editing works the same. Use its Bridge to open by pointing it to any folder your PC can see. It does then build sort of a minimal catalog, which you can completely ignore  It is not a factor, just open any disk folder with images.

Comment: @AramHăvărneanu, you can check the last version of Luminar. IMHO this software do all you want

Comment: You may give a try to Darktable. It really looks like Lr, it is fast, uses graphic acceleration and creates XMP sidecar file. And it's an open source, free software. It works in real fullscreen.

Comment: Probably best suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you define "*catalog*"? My intuition of what it should mean is that requirements 1 and 3 are directly contradictory, so clearly you must understand something different to me.

Comment: Have a look at DxO Photolab and ACDSee. Both have a database where they catalog the photos, but you don't need to import and don't need to use the catalog.

Comment: @WayneF do you want to post your comment as an answer? I will accept it. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Lightroom can work with folders directly without importing them anywhere. I'm not sure why you believe it won't work with network mounted drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, will post as answer, thanks. Works perfectly for me too.

I passed over Lightroom for a similar catalog reason. Too much unwanted stuff between me and my images. I just use Photoshop, it is the same ACR module that is in Lightroom, editing works the same. Use its Bridge to open by pointing it to any folder your PC can see. Select one or many or all images there, then Right click to Open them in ACR.  It does then build sort of a minimal catalog, which you can completely ignore. It is not a factor, just open any disk folder with images.

Answer (score 2):

[Rawtherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/)

It doesn't require importing photos, and works right off of you file system. When you edit a photo it creates a file along side that photo that can contains the edit info, and leaves the photo untouched.

Answer (score 1):

[Aftershot Pro](http://www.aftershotpro.com/en/) is worth considering. It uses an *optional* catalog, so if you know where your files are, you do not need to use it. If we want powerful search, then you can opt in.

It supports RAW. It is quite fast too and has basic controls for photo editing as you ask. I am not a Mac user, so I have no idea what it looks like on a Mac nor if it matches whatever else is there.

Comment: +1 for Aftershot Pro. It's not subscription based, saves XMP data in sidecar files per default and llok native on Mac (based on video tutorials on youtube). (_i'm not affiliated with Aftershot Pro and Corel in any way and used Aftershot several years on Linux_).

Answer (score 0):

I thought of Darktable, too. But it requires importing photos and its UI is far from being designed for photographers like LR and no native OS X/macOS one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at ON1 Photo Raw 2018 www.on1.com ?
It seems to be getting a good number of positive reviews and is available as a 30 day trial - so not much to lose